# agGrid custom cell editor; returning object to Angular component

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am attempting to write a custom cell editor for agGrid implemented in Angular.  In my grid I show the a user readable value of an object within my node, but the object has an `id` which is used throughout my Angular application.  I am trying create an editor in which the user can select basis the user readable value only, but where the editor returns both values so that my app component can use its `id`.

For example, in my app component I have the following `columnDefs` and `rowData`:

```
columnDefs = [
      { headerName: 'City', field: 'city', editable: true, 
          cellEditor: 'cityEditor'},
  ];

rowData = [
      { 'id': 1, 'city': 'Paris' },
      { 'id': 4, 'city': 'Amsterdam' },
  ];
```

In my external editor component I have a dataset to select from:

```
allCitiesRowData = [
        { 'id': 1, 'city': 'Paris', 'country': 'France' },
        { 'id': 2, 'city': 'London', 'country': 'United Kingdom' },
        { 'id': 3, 'city': 'Berlin', 'country': 'Germany' },
        { 'id': 4, 'city': 'Amsterdam', 'country': 'The Netherlands' },
    ];
```

When the user selects my editor component creates an object `selectedCity` with the `id` and `city`, for example `selectedCity = { 'id': 4, 'city': 'Amsterdam' }`.

When the `stopEditing()` is called I can return only 1 value, so for example:

```
getValue(): any {
    return this.selectedCity.city;
}
```

But in this case I have obviously not returned the `id` and my `rowData` nodes will not be correctly updated.  Had I returned `selectedCity.id` or `selectedCity` the edited cell would not show the user readable value of `selectedCity.city`.

Some things I have considered:

- Redesign rowData so that the city is an object of both `id` and `city`, then I could return the `selectedCity` as a direct match.  However I don't think agGrid can hold an object in a cell and only show one of its properties. **Edit**. I realise that a custom cellRenderer could perhaps support this.
- Use `getCellEditorInstances(params)` in my app component to get the value of `selectedCity` however this seems hard as `selectedCity` is set at time of `stopEditing()` and also I would need to find the node that I was editing to set the value which doesn't sound to me like a robust solution.

In a agGrid cell editor, can I return more than the value of the cell so that I can update the cell as well as a secondary value?

Comment: Does your custom cell contain some kind of <select><option> dropdown menu?

Comment: No, it's actually a grid on its own.  So it can rely on <select> to show the correct city value for a given id.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, let me clarify this with you. What you are trying to achieve is that, you want to return the selected object from `allCitiesRowData `, right? Such that the returned value contains not just the id, but the other properties such as `id` and `city`? The returned value will be utilised in the app.component.ts, which is the main/parent component that probably houses your main ag-grid?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.  Right now (after initially posting my question) I am trying to implement this by having `cityObject` with `id` and `city` as the value in `rowData` and then use a `cellRenderer` to show only `cityObject.city` in my cell.  This way I can return `citySelected` (which is the selection from `allCitiesRowData`) in my `cellEditor` and not break my models/objects.

Comment: Hey, I have provided my solution. It seems like we have the same approach too. However, on the cellRenderer, i added an if statement such that the grid will not return an error if it is initialised with an empty row

Comment: Yes, it worked!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have the solution for you, but I am not sure if this is the best practice. Basically, on the `getValue` method, we can simply return the entire object. However, on the main ag-grid, we have to call the cellRenderer property such that we only show the object property (for instance, `city`) on the cell itself.

On your external-editor.component.ts, you can just return the entire object:

```
getValue(): any {
  //lets assume this.selectedRowData contains the object {id: '1', city: 'Paris'}
  this.value = this.selectedRowData;
  console.log(this.value)
  return this.value;
}
```

And on your main app.component.html, you probably have your ag-grid defined this way with the columnDefs:

```
<ag-grid-angular [columnDefs]="columnDefs" ...> </ag-grid-angular>
```

On your app.component.ts, you can include the cellRenderer property to select the property you want to be displayed on your cell! I added an if statement to check for the `params`, as the cellRenderer might throw an error if `params` or `params.value` is `undefined`

```
columnDefs = [
  { 
    headerName: 'City', 
    field: 'city', 
    editable: true, 
    cellEditorFramework: ExternalEditorComponent, 
    cellRenderer: (params) => {
      if (params && params.value) {
        console.log(params.value) // this will print the object with id and city
        return params.value.city;
      }
    },
  },
]
```